# Python split powershell funcrions in into files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a powershell module file that has 200+ functions of many sizes. I like to split each function in the file and output the fuction to its own file and the file name being the name of the function.

Here are some samples of what the fucntions look like. The objective is to split the function code and fucntion name into its own file.

```
Function get-serverlist{
Some code
some code
some code
}

Function get-windowsServices{
Some code
some code
some code

}
```

The code below imports file text into data variable but how would I create the split to export all functions to its own individual file by function name.

```
# import file into a variable
pstext = open(C:/user/someuser/powershell.txt)
data = pstext.read()

#This line will parse out all the functions
fnText = data.split('\nFunction ')

#Sending each line to a file by function name still a mystery.
```

File was converted from .psm1 to txt file as the read function had issues with psm1 extensions